# How can I insert this Function in Simulink? (Rotational 2 DOF)

Tags: rotation, simulink

I want to insert the below function K, in my simulink model, to calculate the dynamic transmission error (dte).

The problem is the function K depend on Θp. I don't know if there is any way to do that in simulink.

I would appreciate any suggest.

[Here you can find the simulink model](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/271596-rotational-2-dof-simulink-problemational-2-dof-simulink-problem)

[Simulink Model (NEW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c58pD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/note: Answer has been rewritten completely.

You can't use a gain block. Any parameter like "Gain" is only evaluated once at the start of the simulation. If you have something which changes over time like your Θp you have to use the signal.

In your case having a one line MATLAB expression to evaluate, the easiest way to use it is a "Function Block" (User-Defined Functons->Fcn), not a MATLAB Function as I originally suggested. Replace the MATLAB Function you already got in your code with a Function Block and use the code:

```
a0 + sum( af .* cos(n * zp * u) + bf .* sin(n * zp * u) )
```

The nice advantage is, that all workspace variables are already initialized.

I applied some modifications to the formula, using element-wise multiplication where I expect it should be used. You can use the same code line in MATLAB to verify it really does what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Due to my limited knowledge in Simulink, I can't understand some things.                                                                   To begin with, I have changed the simulink model and I have attached the picture above. Is model correct now? I can't understand how to write the function inside the matlab function block.

Comment: y = a0 + sum ( af(n) . * cos(n * zp * u) + bf(n) . * sin(n * zp * u) ); this is what I wrote inside but it's wrong

Comment: You need to read the other variables from the base workspace, either using a constant block for each variable and input it to the matlabfunction block as well, or use `evalin`.

Comment: I read the other variables from the workspace and I got error "Undefined function or variable 'a0'." but when I put the a0 as number inside the Matlab Function Block says Undefined function or variable 'af'. etc... btw the Simulink Model is now ok? because you told me to change it...

Comment: I will update my answer with detailed instructions to implement it. Just to make sure I understood it right: The workspace variables are `a0`, `af`, `u` and `bf`. n is 1:8 and `zp` is Θp?

Comment: From workspace: a0 (1 value), n=1: 8, af (8 value) and bf (8 value). u is Θp. Do you want me to change anything else to simulink model? Is it correct now? I have add a MATLAB Function block and a Product Block as you said. I have update the picture above.

Comment: If u is Θp, what is zp?

Comment: click "Here you can find the simulink model" above, I have upload the function and the simulink model

Comment: @Bob: Writing my first answer I did not realize you have only one signal. Updated my answer with a much simpler suggestion.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I did what you say and I got this error:    The expression: a0 + sum( af .* cos(n * zp * u) + bf .* sin(n * zp * u) )
in 'Simulink_S/Fcn'
has a syntax error

Comment: I copied it from my answer to verify, I don't get a syntax error. Not sure what is wrong in your case.

Comment: Click on "Simulink Model (NEW)" I have attach the picture of fcn block and error.